# ruby gem - how to make my gem code available for all controllers and make it executable without adding any line of codes in controller

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been working on a experimental gem. And the idea is for each method calls I need to print something. How can I achieve it

```
class MyGem
  def self.put_text
    puts 'execution in progess'
  end
end
```

this would be my gem code. Now If I have to call this inside my controller I would do this

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController
  def method_one
    MyGem.put_text
    do_something
  end

  def method_two
    MyGem.put_text
    do_something_else
  end
end
```

But I want an efficient way to do it such as add Gem to Gemfile and configure somewhere or something like that so that MyGem.put_text will be called automatically for all the methods in all the controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rails has the concepts of *filters* that you can leverage for this.
You can find the details here [Rails filters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

There are three type of filters:

- before
- after
- around

You could either use a *before* or an *around* filter.

```rb
module Filters
  def around_all
    puts "around filter, before action"
    yield
    puts "around filter, after action"
  end

  def before_all
    puts "before filter, before action"
  end

  def after_all
    puts "after filter, after action"
  end
end

ActionController::Base.include(Filters)
ActionController::Base.around_action :around_all
ActionController::Base.before_action :before_all
ActionController::Base.after_action :after_all
```

This will output, besides the usual log output, something like this

```
Started GET "/somethings" for ::1 at 2023-01-14 16:15:40 +0100
Processing by SometingsController#index as HTML 
around filter, before action 
before filter, before action
after filter, after action 
around filter, after action 
Completed 200 OK
```

Around filters are good if you need to have access to local variables or state before and after the action, e.g. timing or object counts.

Note: the *around* filter has a `yield` statement, do not forget this or your action will not be called.